# Ember.js helper not properly recognizing a parameter

Tags: ember.js, handlebars.js

I'm trying to get used to Ember.js and Handlebars, but one problem is puzzling me. I'm probably just missing something, but has been on it for quite a while and could not find anything wrong.

I have the simple template bellow:

```
<header>

    <h2><a href="#" class="link-box-title">{{project.pid}}-{{projectWindowTitle project}}</a></h2>

</header>
```

the first {{project.pid}} correctly outputs the project.pid value, and I wanted to pass the project object to the helper function bellow:

```
Handlebars.registerHelper('projectWindowTitle', function(proj) {

    var info = proj.pid;
    return info;

});
```

I'm overly simplifying the helper, but the result is always the same, the helper does't return anything:

```
<a href="#" class="link-box-title"><script id="metamorph-9-start" type="text/x-placeholder"></script>S2S<script id="metamorph-9-end" type="text/x-placeholder"></script>-</a>
```

What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

when using handlebars in ember.js, the helper signature is a little bit different than with "plain" handlebars. the main difference is that the argument is not "resolved" before the helper is called.

for your example, *proj* is "project", so you have to get the value of "project" from the view:

```
Handlebars.registerHelper('projectWindowTitle', function(property, options) {
    var project = Ember.getPath(this, property);
    var info = project.get("pid");
    return info;
});
```

Comment: Michael's right in that you need to resolve the `project` object from within the helper, since parameters are passed as names. I think this will work once you change the project assignment to `var project = Ember.get(this, property);`.

Answer (score 1):

I know that question already has accepted answer but .. that's not the correct approach :)

As described on [ember docs](http://emberjs.com/guides/templates/writing-helpers/), the proper way of creating handlebars helpers for ember is a bit different than what you would do in handlebars.

Something along the lines of:

```
Ember.Handlebars.helper('projectWindowTitle', function(value) {
  var escaped = Handlebars.Utils.escapeExpression(value.pid);
  return new Handlebars.SafeString(escaped);
});
```