# Ember CLI + HTMLBars -- Passing Parameters to a Helper

Tags: ember.js, ember-cli

I'm trying to pass a parameter from my HTMLBars template to a Helper.

As per the documentation, I've created a helper and explicitly registered the helper:

```
export default Ember.HTMLBars.makeBoundHelper('is-foo', function(value, options) {
   console.log("value: "+value);
});
```

But I get an error "Error: Assertion Failed: makeBoundHelper generated helpers do not support use with blocks"

So I've tried using Ember.HTMLBars.helper and Ember.HTMLBars.registerHelper as suggested [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9261976/ember-js-helper-not-properly-recognizing-a-parameter) but I get errors "TypeError: Ember.default.HTMLBars.helper is not a function"

If I don't reigster the helper explicitly:

```
export default function(value, options) {
   console.log("value: "+value);
};
```

Then I can pass a parameter, but it doesn't get resolved and logs out the literal text of what I passed.

So I tried the solution outlined [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9261976/ember-js-helper-not-properly-recognizing-a-parameter) but it doesn't seem to work with CLI

The result I want is for a component to be dynamically selected based on the value of the parameter I send to the helper.  My HTMLBars code looks like:

```
{{#each foo in model}}
  {{is-foo parameter}}
    {{a-component}}
  {{else}}
    {{another-component}}
  {{/is-foo}}
{{/each}}
```

I'm not sure what to do next.  Any help is appreciated.

Comment: with CLI use `ember g helper foo`.  It will create a foo helper for you.  Then you can look at its code to see how you can make your own manually.

Comment: Thank you for the response!  I generated a helper with CLI, but it also creates a bound helper that I can't use with blocks.  Basically I need a way to conditionally choose a component from my template, but I can't find any way to get it working.

Comment: Please give your HTMLBars code.

Comment: I've updated the question with the HTMLBars code.

Comment: Since: "The result I want is for a component to be dynamically selected based on the value of the parameter I send to the helper." possible duplicate of [How to include a component from a controller in ember](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/29777886/how-to-include-a-component-from-a-controller-in-ember)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Do something like this in Ember CLI project, because helper file name is the helper name

```
export default Ember.HTMLBars.makeBoundHelper(function(value, options) {
```

instead of

```
export default Ember.HTMLBars.makeBoundHelper('is-foo', function(value, options) {
```

**Edit**

Upon @TheCompiler 's request here is the suggestion as an answer.

Do something like in HTMLBars

```
{{if is_parameter}}
  {{a-component}}
{{else}}
  {{another-component}}
{{/if}}
```

In Controller or Component the computed `parameter` property

```
is_parameter: function () {
  var pm = this.get('parameter');

  return (your condition for `pm`)? true : false;
}.property('parameter')
```

Comment: Thanks, but it still gives me the error "Error: Assertion Failed: makeBoundHelper generated helpers do not support use with blocks".  I just don't understand how to get around this.  I want to dynamically choose a component from my template based on a parameter value, but how am I supposed to do that when I can't use conditions with helpers?

Comment: @TheCompiler You should use computed properties as if conditionals, not Helpers.

Comment: Yeah, that's what I ended up doing.  If you want to make this suggestion a new answer I'll mark it as accepted.

Comment: When passing multiple parameters, those are given as array, so that you can read them as following `export default Ember.HTMLBars.makeBoundHelper(function(parameter, options) {var param1=parameter[0];var param2=parameter[1];console.log("p1:"+param1+" p2:"+param2);});`

Answer (score 0):

The behavior that you want is achieved in [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/29778657/7852).

If you would like to know how the `component` helper is implemented you can check its source code here: [helpers/component.js](https://stackoverflow.com/a/29778657/7852) (currently line 63)